# Access not within mapped region

Tags: c

I have the following code, which will takes a phone number, containing numbers and symbols and produces a string only containing the number.

```
char* turnIntoNumber(const char* tel)
{
    unsigned int length_tel = strlen(tel);

    char* number_start = 0x0;
    number_start = (char*) malloc(length_tel + 1);

    if(number_start == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"couldn't allocate memory for turnIntoNumber(const char*)");
        exit(1);
    }
    char* number = number_start;

    int index = 0;

    for(;tel != '\0'; ++tel)
    {
        if(isNumber(*tel))
        {
            number[index] = *tel;

            index++;
        }
    }

    number[index] = '\0';

    return number_start;
}
```

When running the program I recieve a Sig Segfault.
Running the program under valgrind tells me that I have a "access not within mapped region".

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Can you tell me, where the error is?

Comment: to resolve a segfault, first use `gdb`. and what is `isNumber()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to compare `tel` with `'\0'` (`tel != '\0'`) at line 17 in the `for` loop.  You mean `*tel != '\0'`.